# Issue with Planet Labs API - scenes filtered by area of interest do not intersect AOI

Tags: planet

I've obtained a list of item IDs that intersect my AOI using 
`api.filters.geom_filter(aoi)` and this list has lots of scenes in it. However, when I attempt to download these scenes clipped to the exact same AOI, I get a returned message saying `'AOI does not intersect with PSScene3Band/20180815_163343_1043`.

This error only happens for very few scenes, i.e. 2-5 out of 100 but it prevents me from doing a mass download. I am confused as to how a scene can pass the intersection filter and then fail to have an intersection during the clipping operation.

I am using the V1 API for searching and the V2 API for clipping and downloading. The request that I submit to the V2 API is the following:

`{'name': 'farm_clipped',
 'products': [{'item_ids': ['20180821_165023_1105',
    '20180928_165956_1027',
    ...
    '20180815_163343_1043'],
   'item_type': 'PSScene3Band',
   'product_bundle': 'visual'}],
 'tools': [{'clip': {'aoi': {'coordinates': [[[-98.44, 46.29],
       [-98.38, 46.29],
       [-98.44, 46.25],
       [-98.38, 46.25],
       [-98.44, 46.29]]],
     'type': 'Polygon'}}}]}`

I've abbreviated the list of item IDs, but have left in one of the IDs (`20180815_163343_1043`)that leads to a failure.

Comment: Please provide the AOI and any API calls that you are making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two geometries (`20180815_163343_1043`'s footprint and your AOI) do not, in fact, intersect as can be seen here:
[image]

The reason you are likely running into this issue is that search using Planet's Data API does occasionally return non-intersecting results. This is rare but can happen with complex polygons or in other, less predictable, circumstances. The `strict` parameter can help filter these false positives out when searching: https://developers.planet.com/docs/api/reference/#operation/QuickSearch.